# Simplify $n$th derivative of $\frac{\log^3 x}{1-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, logarithms

> I need to simplify $n$th derivative of $$f(x)=\frac{\log^3 x}{1-x}$$ where $0<x<1$

I tried writing $f(x)=u_1u_2u_3u_4$ where $u_1=u_2=u_3=\log x$ and $u_4=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Using [Leibniz rule for $n$th derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471734/the-n-th-derivative-of-the-product-of-three-functions) we get $$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=n} \binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2},k_{3},k_{4}}u_1^{(k_{1})}u_2^{(k_{2})}u_3^{(k_{3})}u_4^{(k_{4})}$$
Now we have using $u_1^{(k_1)}=\frac{(-1)^{k_1+1} (k_1-1)!}{x^{k_1}}$ and $u_4^{(k_4)}=\frac{k_4!}{(1-x)^{1+k_4}}$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=n} \left(\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!k_4!}\right)\frac{(-1)^{k_1+1} (k_1-1)!(-1)^{k_2+1} (k_2-1)!(-1)^{k_3+1} (k_3-1)!k_4!}{x^{k_1+k_2+k_3} (1-x)^{1+k_4}} $$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=n!\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=n} \frac{(-1)^{k_1+k_2+k_3+1}}{k_1k_2k_3 x^{k_!+k_2+k_3}(1-x)^{1+k_4}} $$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{n!(-1)^{n+1}}{x^n}\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=n} \frac{(-1)^{k_4}}{k_1k_2k_3}\frac{x^{k_4}}{(1-x)^{1+k_4}} $$
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can expand the logarithm to a power [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/) or find a [pattern](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BD%5Bf%28ln%28x%29%29%2C%7Bx%2Cn%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D), finite sum, for $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(\ln(x))$ which both require [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Thanks a lot. It would be really helpful if you could please write as an answer showing the steps involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the Leibniz rule:
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{\ln^3(x)}{1-x}=\sum_{m=0}^n\binom nm\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\ln^3(x)\frac{d^{n-m}}{dx^{n-m}}\frac1{1-x}$$

Now use the Stirling number of the first kind [$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\ln^a(x)$ formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/20/02/0004/) and simplify the resulting factorials to get:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{\ln^3 (x)}{1-x}=6n!\sum_{k=0}^4\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{S_m^{(k)}\ln^{3-k}(x)(1-x)^{m-n-1}}{\Gamma(4-k)\ln(x)^{k-3}x^mm!}$$

Expanding the outer sum and [converting](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/03/01/01/) $S_m^{(k)}$ into [(generalized) Harmonic numbers](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/HarmonicNumber2/) finally gives:

$$\boxed{\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{\ln^3 (x)}{1-x}=\frac{n!\ln^3(x)}{(1-x)^{n+1}}+3(-1)^nn!\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{(x-1)^{m-n-1}}{mx^m}\left(\left((H_{m-1}-\ln(x)\right)^2-H_{m-1}^{(2)}\right)}$$

which is [true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Bln%28x%29%5E3%2F%281-x%29%2C%7Bx%2C7%7D%5D%3DLim%5Bn%21+ln%28x%29%5E3%2F%281-x%29%5E%28n%2B1%29+%2B+Sum%5B3+%28-1%29%5En+n%21+%28x-1%29%5E%28-1+%2B+m+-+n%29%2F%28m+x%5Em%29+%28%28HarmonicNumber%5B-1+%2B+m%5D+-+Log%5Bx%5D%29%5E2-harmonic%28m-1%2C2%29%29%2C%7Bm%2C1%2C7%7D%5D%2Cn-%3E7%5D). You can expand and sum over $\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\frac{(x-1)^{m-n-1}}{mx^m}$ and get a [Lerch transcendent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html), but the sums over the harmonic numbers do not seem to have a special function form

Comment: I am accepting your beautiful answer. Thanks.